# What's the easiest way to find if this series is monotonic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

This is my sequence:
$$a_n=\frac{3^n-4^n}{2^n-n+1}$$

So I am supposed to check how it is monotonic. Thats what i tried to run using wolfram, but honestly it gets complicated easily

$$\frac{3^{n+1}-4^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}-n}-\frac{3^n-4^n}{2^n-n+1}$$

I honestly don't know what to do after altering forms

Comment: Does it help to rewrite the expression for the nth term in the sequence as $\frac{(3/2)^n - 2^n}{1 - \frac{n-1}{2^n}}$ ?  The numerator decreases faster and faster as the denominator gets closer and closer to 1 . . .

Comment: @DCarter it looks promising, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider

$$a_n=\frac{3^n-4^n}{2^n-n+1}=\frac{3^n-4^n}{4^n}\cdot \frac{4^n}{2^n-n+1}=b_n \cdot c_n$$

and

$$b_n=\frac{3^n-4^n}{4^n}=\left(\frac34\right)^n-1$$

is negative strictly decreasing while

$$c_n=\frac{4^n}{2^n-n+1}$$

is positive strictly increasing indeed

$$\frac{4^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}-n}-\frac{4^n}{2^n-n+1}=4^n\left(\frac{4}{2^{n+1}-n}-\frac{1}{2^n-n+1}\right)>0$$

and

$$\frac{4}{2^{n+1}-n}-\frac{1}{2^n-n+1}>0\iff 4(2^n-n+1)> 2^{n+1}-n$$

$$2^{n+2}-2^{n+1}-3n+4>0 \iff 2^{n+1}-3n+4>0$$

which is true, therefore the product $b_n \cdot c_n$ is strictly decreasing.